# SQLServerBulkCopy in jdbc error SybResultSet.isClosed()Z is abstract

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

i am new to java, i am trying to connect do bulkcopy from sybase to SQL server database.

i used the jdbc3, i am getting the below error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/sybase/jdbc3/jdbc/SybResultSet.isClosed()Z is abstract
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybResultSet.isClosed(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeResultSet(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:574)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:533)
at SQLServer.dbConnect(SQLServer.java:36)
at SQLServer.main(SQLServer.java:46)

i have follwoing questinos

1. which jdbc driver works with com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy
2. is there any other alternative

Comment: jdbc3? From before Java SE 7? Perhaps you should choose a more modern Java runtime and JDBC drivers appropriate to the version of SQL Server you're targeting. Start by going through the [SQL Server version compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix#sql-version-compatibility).

Comment: thanks you so much.. it worked with jdbc4